# Prolog - Parsing

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

I'm new to the language prolog and have been given an assignment regarding parsing in prolog. I need some help in solving the problem.

In the assingment we have the grammar:

```
Expr ::= + Expr Expr | * Expr Expr | Num | Xer  
Xer  ::= x | ^ x Num  
Num  ::= 2 | 3 | .... a Integer (bigger than 1) ...
```

The token `^` is the same as in math. `5^5` equals `25`.

Parse needs to work both ways: a call with an instantiated list to generate an Ast, while
a call with an instantiated Ast should generate similar prefix list.

My assingment says that I need to make a prefix parse that does this:
Example(with the value of Ast removed):

```
?- parse([+, *, 2, x, ^, x, 5 ], Ast), parse(L, Ast).  
X = ...,  
L = [+, *, 2, x, ^, x, 5]
```

I would also like to know how the parse tree will look like.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Why do you vote this is as off-topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prolog has a particular formalism to handle context-free grammars directly: DCGs (Definite Clause Grammars). Your example translates almost immediately into a DCG:

```
expr --> [+], expr, expr | [*], expr, expr | num | xer.

xer --> [x] | [^], [x], num.

num --> [2] | [3] | [4] | [5].
```

Now, you already can test sentences:

```
?- phrase(expr, [+,*,2,x,^,x,5]).
   true
;  false.
?- phrase(expr, [+,*,*,2,x,^,x,5]).
   false.
```

You can even generate all possible sentences like so:

```
?- length(L, N), phrase(expr, L).
   L = [2], N = 1
;  L = [3], N = 1
;  ... .
```

And, finally, you can add the abstract syntax tree to your definition.

```
expr(plus(A,B)) --> [+], expr(A), expr(B).
expr(mul(A,B)) --> [*], expr(A), expr(B).
expr(Num) --> num(Num).
expr(Xer) --> xer(Xer).

xer(var(x)) --> [x].
xer(pow(var(x),N)) --> [^], [x], num(N).

num(num(2)) --> [2].
num(num(3)) --> [3].
num(num(4)) --> [4].
num(num(5)) --> [5].
```

So now you can use it as desired:

```
?- phrase(expr(AST), [+,*,2,x,^,x,5]), phrase(expr(AST),L).
   AST = plus(mul(num(2),var(x)),pow(var(x),num(5))),
   L = [+,*,2,x,^,x,5]
;  false.
```

Just a nitpick: The interface predicate to DCGs is `phrase/2` not `parse/2`.

Comment: I'm still working on my assingment, and I need your help again. Have been trying to solve the problem for some time now. Now I'm suppose to make a predicate ev(+Ast,+Env,Value) that evaluate the value of an AST with a known value for "Env"(With a higher value than integer 1).
   
Examples with Env = 2:   
parse([x],Ast), ev(Ast, 2, 2 ).
parse([*, 2, ^, x, 3],Ast), ev(Ast, 2, 16).
parse([+, ^, x, 2, *, 4, ^, x, 3],Ast), ev(Ast, 2, 36).

Comment: So far I have:
  
ev(Ast, Env, Value) :- eva((Ast), Env, V), V = Value.
  
eva(X,V) :- number(X), V is X.
eva(mul(A,B),V):- eva(A, A2), eva(B, B2), V is A2*B2.
eva(plus(A,B), V):- eva(A, A2), eva(B, B2), V is A2+B2.

Comment: @Taza: Please look around - there is an answer to this already! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916466/prolog-solving-prefix-arithmetic-expression-with-unknown-variable