# Prolog solving prefix arithmetic expression with unknown variable

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg, arithmetic-expressions

I want to make an arithmetic solver in Prolog that can have +,-,*,^ operations on numbers >= 2. It should also be possible to have a variable x in there. The input should be a prefix expression in a list.

I have made a program that parses an arithmetic expression in prefix format into a syntax tree. So that:

```
?- parse([+,+,2,9,*,3,x],Tree).
Tree = plus(plus(num(2), num(9)), mul(num(3), var(x))) .
```

**(1)** At this stage, I want to extend this program to be able to solve it for a given x value. This should be done by adding another predicate **evaluate(Tree, Value, Solution)** which given a value for the unknown x, calculates the solution.

Example:

```
?- parse([*, 2, ^, x, 3],Tree), evaluate(Ast, 2, Solution).
Tree = mul(num(2), pow(var(x), num(3))) ,
Solution = 16.
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem due to my lack of Prolog skills, but I need a way of setting the var(x) to num(2) like in this example (because x = 2). Maybe **member** in Prolog can be used to do this. Then I have to solve it using perhaps **is/2**

**Edit**: My attempt to solving it. Getting error: '*Undefined procedure: evaluate/3 However, there are definitions for: evaluate/5*'

```
evaluate(plus(A,B),Value,Sol) --> evaluate(A,AV,Sol), evaluate(B,BV,Sol), Value is AV+BV.
evaluate(mul(A,B),Value,Sol) --> evaluate(A,AV,Sol), evaluate(B,BV,Sol), Value is AV*BV.
evaluate(pow(A,B),Value,Sol) --> evaluate(A,AV,Sol), evaluate(B,BV,Sol), Value is AV^BV.
evaluate(num(Num),Value,Sol) --> number(Num).
evaluate(var(x),Value,Sol) --> number(Value).
```

**(2)** I'd also want to be able to express it in postfix form. Having a predicate **postfixform(Tree, Postfixlist)**

Example:

```
?- parse([+, *, 2, x, ^, x, 5 ],Tree), postfix(Tree,Postfix).
Tree = plus(mul(num(2), var(x)), pow(var(x), num(5))) ,
Postfix = [2, x, *, x, 5, ^, +].
```

Any help with **(1)** and **(2)** would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The first part: is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793480/prolog-parsing.

Comment: @false Yes, thanks! I used your approach to implement the first part, but I'm stuck in my approach for (1) and (2). Any ideas?

Comment: The last part is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131640/remove-ambiguity-in-abstract-syntax-in-other-to-write-dcg-parser-prolog/13143803#13143803

Comment: The part in the middle is not that clear. Do you permit several variables?

Comment: @false Thanks again. No, only one variable x. So in evaluate(Tree, Value, Solution), Value will always correspond to the value of x.

Comment: So you need a different interface: You need to be able to indicate several variables at once.

Comment: I was considering this approach. http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/arithmetics.html In my example it would be `eval_v(plus(A,B),CV,Vars):-eval_v(A,AV,Vars),eval_v(B,BV,Vars),CV is AV+BV.
eval_v(mul(A,B),CV,Vars):-eval_v(A,AV,Vars),eval_v(B,BV,Vars),CV is AV*BV.
eval_v(pow(A,B),CV,Vars):-eval_v(A,AV,Vars),eval_v(B,BV,Vars),CV is AV^BV.
eval_v(Num,Num,Vars):-number(Num).
eval_v(Var,Value,Vars):-atom(Var),member(Var/Value,Vars)` but there seems to be something wrong with it. Any idea?

Comment: You are putting too much into a single question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Have a look at my attempt at solving it. I edited the main question.

Comment: This site works if you ask a clear question. Not everything at once. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a grammar for this, as you are doing. You should use normal rules.

This is the pattern you need to follow.

```
evaluate(plus(A,B),Value,Sol) :- 
   evaluate(A, Value, A2),
   evaluate(B, Value, B2),
   Sol is A2+B2.
```

And

```
evaluate(num(X),_Value,Sol) :- Sol = X.
evaluate(var(x),Value,Sol) :- Sol = Value.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried normal rules as well, but I did a typo 'Value is ...' instead of 'Sol is ...' Now it's working fine!

Comment: Of course! Could you have a look at my other problem with my implementation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959722/prolog-numbers-greater-than-x Thanks!