# Prolog - Numbers greater than x

Tags: prolog, dcg, arithmetic-expressions

I'm working with Prolog arithmetic and have a program that generates an abstract syntax tree, such as `plus(num(1),num(2))` which simply is `1+2`. This is done by using DCG. In this example `plus(num(1),num(2))` is the same as the prefix list representation `[+,1,2]`.

My problem is that I only want to allow `num(x)` greater than 3. For example `num(4)` is allowed but not `num(1)`.

I'm doing this by:

```
num(num(4)) --> [4].
num(num(5)) --> [5].
num(num(6)) --> [6].
num(num(7)) --> [7].
```

etc. but would like to do something like `num(num(x)) --> [x].` for numbers greater than 3. Any idea as to how to approach this problem?

Comment: @ChristianF Yes, it's an exercise! I'm willing to learn, so just the slightest hint will be appreciated! :) I've been researching, but it's not a lot of Prolog-stuff out there...

Comment: You don't seem to understand the concept of variables in Prolog. Read up about that. After that, read up about DCGs. You shouldn't use it in this case. Then, realize that it is trivial to check X > 3.

Comment: Thanks again! Figured it out ;)

Comment: @ExceptionalException: Then write your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
num(num(X)) --> [X], {X > 3}
```

The {}/1 can be used to embed conditions and side effects
in DCG grammar rules. DCGs are found in many Prolog systems
but there is not yet a ripe standard. But most of the Prolog
systems do have the {}/1. It is for example defined here:

**Definite Clause Grammar Rules**
Klaus Daessler
August 20, 2013
http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dcgs/dcgsdin130820.pdf

In the glossary the {}/1 goes as "grammar body goal". In older
publications the construct was called "auxiliary action", "procedure 
call" or "extra conditions", which is probably more sensible than 
just calling it grammar body goal, since we would like to see all 
constituents of a grammar body as grammar body goals. See for 
example here:

**Definite Clause Grammars for Language Analysis**
Fernando C. N. Pereira and David H. D. Warren
Artificial Intelligence 13 (1980), 231-278
http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~takis/pereira-warren.pdf

Bye