# How can I test a phrase with a context free grammar writing with DCG prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a context free grammar which I have written in DCG prolog. I also have some example phrases in the language. I want to test each example phrase with the context free grammar in order to verify that the context free grammar is correct. Please how can I do this in prolog?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19797941/772868) example.

Comment: And [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401614/772868), a more complex example.

Comment: Can you show at least one example call in your grammar as implemented in Prolog, with an example phrase as you want to provide it?